# Why is requests.get() not working in a for loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape a list of websites which are listed in the text file 'tastyrecipes', I currently have a for loop which returns the urls, but can't figure out how to put the urls into requests.get() without getting a 404 error. The websites return a 200 status code individually and there's no problems viewing the HTML.

I have tried string formatting, where I did

```
with open('tastyrecipes', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        source = requests.get("{0}".format(i))
```

however this didn't change the result.

```
with open('tastyrecipes', 'r') as f:
    new_file = open("recipecorpus.txt", "a+")
    for i in f:
        source = requests.get(i)
        content = source.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        list_object = soup.find('ol', class_='prep-steps list-unstyled xs-text-3')
        method = list_object.text
        new_file.write(method)
        new_file.close()
```

I anticipated i to allow for iterative scraping over the urls in the text file, however it returns a 404 error.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation and quoting, as well as create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't require some file we don't know the contents of in order to help debug your issue? Also, did you try putting a debug statement before the request and see what the string is getting set to before it's requested?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with my indentation and quoting, and I tried to create a minimal example above my full code. I didn't think that the contents of the file were important in the sense that, as I said, it is just a list of urls. I didn't put a debug statement as I would have to look up how to do that

Comment: Given the nature of HHTP requests, it's very likely the site is denying your rapid connection attempts or rate-limiting your IP. Perhaps look into adding some `time.sleep`s into your code and see if performance improves

Comment: @JonathanDyke I see that you fixed your indentation, and by the quoting I meant the line `('tastyrecipes', 'r'')` contains an extra quote. Also we couldn't have known what was in the file or how it was formatted without you telling or showing us.

Comment: @JonathanDyke I didn't mean a debug statement, I meant a breakpoint for a debugger - if you are not familiar with using a debugger, I highly, highly recommend learning it ASAP, as it's an essential tool. PyCharm comes with one by default.

Comment: I hadn't thought about it being a requests issue @G.Anderson thanks for the response. If it is then it sounds as though the requests.get(i) should be ok. Also, Random Davis I have removed the quote and altered the text to make it clear that the text file to which I was referring was that which was being read during the for loop.

Comment: If one URL returns 200, and another one 404, the 2 URLs are different.

Comment: @RandomDavis thanks for the advice, I use PyCharm but with minimal experience so I'll have a look into that

Comment: a) share a portion of your `tastyrecipes`, e.g. 2-3 lines, b) instead of `new_file.write` create a `results=[]` and then `results.append(method`), c) `print(results)` and edit your post

Comment: Hey Jonathan, would you mind posting a small snippet of your `tastyrecipes` file?

Comment: @IMCoins I think that it may be a request issue, as G. Anderson said, as the 200 status code was for the first url in the text file, i.e. the same url worked when it wasn't being parsed in through a for loop.

Comment: It is **very** unlikely that it's a requests issue.

Comment: @JonathanDyke there is nothing wrong per se with 404 or even 50x results. Maybe the content of your `tastyrecipes` is a culprit

Comment: @AlexYu I have shared a few lines of tastyrecipes, if it is of importance the indentation is intentional; in the text file all urls after the first are indented.

Comment: So trailing newlines was the culprit?

Comment: Yes, the code worked after doing i = i.rstrip('\r\n')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines `i` in the file `f` are returned with trailing newlines, which do not belong in normal URLs.  You need to remove the newlines with `i = i.rstrip('\r\n')` before passing `i` to `requests.get()`.

Comment: If that's the problem, he could also do `"""{}""".format(url)` I believe.

Comment: @IMCoins: That's the same as `url`, just with extra steps.

Comment: Let's wait for `tastyrecipes` snippet

Answer (score 0):

## Analysis

It was impossible for me to find a problem with `requests.get` per se.

```
import requests
recipes=['https://tasty.co/recipe/deep-fried-ice-cream-dogs',
        'https://tasty.co/recipe/fried-shrimp-and-mango-salsa-hand-rolls',
         'https://tasty.co/recipe/brigadeiros']
```

> ```
> print(list(map(requests.get, recipes)))
> [<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>]
>
> for recipe in recipes: print(requests.get(recipe))
> <Response [200]>
> <Response [200]>
> <Response [200]>
> ```

## Possible problems

### 1. 404 is not a problem itself

It is a legitimate answer if there are incorrect urls.

### 2. Trailing \n and whitespaces in `tastyrecipes`-file

That was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54598985/1168212) by @jwodder

Comment: Yeah it was the trailing whitespaces in the file which caused an error, I had a look at the contents of the text file in terminal and it seems to be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

first check url is valid or not 
`from urlparse import urlsplit
def is_valid_url(url=''):
    url_parts = urlsplit(url)
    return url_parts.scheme and url_parts.netloc and surl_partsp.path`

`with open('tastyrecipes', 'r') as f:
    new_file = open("recipecorpus.txt", "a+")
    for i in f:
        if is_valid_url(i)
            source = requests.get(i)
            content = source.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
            list_object = soup.find('ol', class_='prep-steps list-unstyled xs-text-3')
            method = list_object.text
            new_file.write(method)
            new_file.close()`